# How to make a newline in a align environment?

Tags: align

I have a formula like:

```
\begin{align}\frac { \partial f } { \partial l } \Big| _ { ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_{0} ) } &= f _ { x } ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_0 ) \cos  \alpha + f _ { y } ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_{0} ) \cos \beta +f _ { z } ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_{0} ) \cos \gamma \\
&=\nabla f \cdot \vec { e } &
 \end{align}
```

[image]

But it is too long for me. I have the red arrow "+" align the blue arrow "+" in a newline. So I use two `&` to implement it:

```
\begin{align}\frac { \partial f } { \partial l } \Big| _ { ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_{0} ) } &= f _ { x } ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_0 ) \cos  \alpha &+ f _ { y } ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_{0} ) \cos \beta \\ &&+f _ { z } ( x _ { 0 } , y _ { 0 },z_{0} ) \cos \gamma \\
&=\nabla f \cdot \vec { e } &
\end{align}
```

[image]

But now I get some redundant blank...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial l } \Big|_{ ( x_0, y_0, z_0 ) } 
    &= f_x ( x_0, y_0, z_0 ) \cos\alpha && + f_y ( x_0, y_0, z_0 ) \cos\beta  \\ 
    &                                   && + f_z ( x_0, y_0, z_0 ) \cos\gamma \\
    &= \nabla f \cdot \vec{ e }
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I can propose two ways: in the first one the equation number is aligned to the first line, in the second one it is midway.

In the second case we need to manually add a “phantom”, because `split` only accepts one alignment point. We also need to “bottom smash” the fraction so to avoid too much white space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\frac {\partial f}{\partial l}\Big|_{(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})} 
  & = f_{x}(x_{0},y_{0},z_0) \cos\alpha 
      \begin{aligned}[t]
      &+ f_{y}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \cos\beta \\
      &+ f_{z}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \cos\gamma
     \end{aligned}
\\
  &= \nabla f \cdot \vec{e}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{\frac {\partial f}{\partial l}\Big|_{(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})}}
  & = f_{x}(x_{0},y_{0},z_0) \cos\alpha + f_{y}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \cos\beta \\
  & \hphantom{{}=f_{x}(x_{0},y_{0},z_0) \cos\alpha} + f_{z}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \cos\gamma
\end{split} \\
  &= \nabla f \cdot \vec{e}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Uhm, any particular reason for the `\hphantom`? I would've used an `{aligned}[t]` (nested in the `split`) also in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do using `\mkern158.648mu`. The number 158.648 (`mu` it is the unit measure) has been chosen after many compilations.
It is not a correct mode but it can be a trick to solve your question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial l} \bigg|_ {(x_{0}, y_{0},z_{0})}& = f_{x} (x _{0}, y_{0},z_0) \cos  \alpha + f_{y}(x_{0}, y_{ 0 },z_{0}) \cos \beta \\
&\mkern158.648mu+f_{z} (x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \cos \gamma \\
&=\boldsymbol{\nabla} f \cdot \vec {e}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

First image:

[image]

Second image (with zoom):

[image]

Comment: Erm, I seriously doubt that the decimals are useful. With your setup `0.01mu` correspond to 2 *micro*meters.

Comment: @campa Hi. :-). I have done several compilations. And I have seen that a bit the plus sign shift to right or left. Please, can you tried? Thank you very much for your advice.